# Tab content in ionic framework does not scroll down in ios and android

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, tabs

I cannot scroll down the content in my `Custom` tab. If I used

```
<ion-content scroll="true">   // This will make problem in iOS. In Android this was fine.
</ion-content>
```

Android:

[image: Android View]

iOS:

[image: iOS View]

Here is my code for your reference:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-pencil-purple">
        <a ng-href="#/home"  class="button back-button buttons  button-clear header-item"><i class="icon ion-android-arrow-back"></i> <span class="back-text" style=""></span></a>
        <div class="title title-left header-item" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); left: 31px;">
            Manage my study
        </div>
      </div>
    <!--<ion-content>-->
        <ion-tabs class="choose-subject-tab">
        <ion-tab title="Custom" >
          <div class="padding pt135 choose-subject-bg">
            <div class="prefer-subject-desc">Select your preferred subject</div>
            <div class="row mb16">
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2" ng-click="showPopup('English')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-eng">
                            {{SubjectData['eng']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.eng.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['eng']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['eng']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-sc" ng-click="showPopup('Science')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-sc">
                            {{SubjectData['sc']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.sc.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['sc']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['sc']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-m3" ng-click="showPopup('Mathematics')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-m3">
                            {{SubjectData['m3']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.m3.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['m3']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['m3']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb16">
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-geo" ng-click="showPopup('Geography')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-geo">
                            {{SubjectData['geo']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.geo.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['geo']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['geo']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-sej" ng-click="showPopup('Sejarah')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-sej">
                            {{SubjectData['sej']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.sej.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['sej']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['sej']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-phy" ng-click="showPopup('Physics')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-phy">
                            {{SubjectData['phy']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.phy.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['phy']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['phy']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb16">
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-che" ng-click="showPopup('Chemistry')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-che">
                            {{SubjectData['che']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.che.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['che']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['che']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-bio" ng-click="showPopup('Biology')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-bio">
                            {{SubjectData['bio']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.bio.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['bio']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['bio']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-33">  
                    <div class="round-button-subject-2 subject-kh" ng-click="showPopup('Kemahiran Hidup')">
                        <div class="subject-name-2 subject-kh">
                            {{SubjectData['kh']['subject']}}
                        </div>
                        <circular-progress
                            value = "SubjectData.kh.value"
                            max="100"
                            orientation="1"
                            radius="36"
                            stroke="5"
                            base-color="#fff"
                            progress-color="{{SubjectData['kh']['color']}}"
                            iterations="100"
                            animation="easeInOutCubic"
                        ></circular-progress>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subject-percentage">
                        {{SubjectData['kh']['value']}}%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#/question-details/0" class="button-study button button-energized">
                        <div class="row btn-study-row">
                            <div class="col study-text">
                                STUDY
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Study List">
            <div class="choose-subject-bg pt135">
                <ion-floating-button ng-click="addNewStudyList()" has-footer="false" button-color="orange" icon="ion-plus" icon-color="#fff">
                </ion-floating-button>
                <div class="study-card-item">
                    <div class="icon-study-list">
                        <img src="img/icon-button-study.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="study-list-item">
                        <div class="title">Subjek Teras</div>
                        <div class="description">Bahasa Melayu, English</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="study-sub-menu" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="study-card-item">
                    <div class="icon-study-list">
                        <img src="img/icon-button-study.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="study-list-item">
                        <div class="title">Subjek Teras</div>
                        <div class="description">Bahasa Melayu, English</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="study-sub-menu" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-tab>
      </ion-tabs>
    <!--</ion-content>-->
</ion-view>
```